# R package for visualizing qualitative data -- coding events that occur over time

Tags: r

I'm fairly new to R, so I was hoping I could be pointed in the right direction.

I am looking for a package that allows me to construct graphs of some qualitative data.
The qualitative data consists of certain coded events that happen during during 30 minute chunks of time. The original data are from recorded videos, and the different events that occur have different codes. Ideally, the graphs would be a horizontal band divided into appropriately sized smaller chunks based on how long/when the different coded events occur during the 30 minute period. The idea is to provide a visual of what happens during various 30-minute chunks of time for different individuals. I am open to other types of visuals if they also seem appropriate! Thanks!

Comment: Looks like a good use case for [timevis](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/timevis/vignettes/timevis.html) package

Comment: Another possible option would be [vistime](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/vistime/vignettes/vistime-vignette.html) package